# How to notify not active PWA app about new content in DB?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, api, progressive-web-apps

I am building PWA app on Vue.js, which is supposted to "listen for updates in background" (when one device add value to DB, the second get information about waiting update).

I had the idea to use socket.io - which worked fine as long as user had active app on mobile - but the problem starts when user close phone, because it stops socket.io too.

Is there any way to "wake up" PWA to synchronization in background? or at least let PWA information to download new data, when user active the app? I was thinking about notify API, but I am not sure how it looks like in 2021. Need option which will work for both, android and IOS.

Could someone please tell me, how to bite the topic?